# Vim encryption: how to break it?

Tags: encryption, vim, vi

Recently I decided to encrypt my engineering log using vim's :X 
encryption feature. I wrote down the password, but evidently I 
misspelled something or messed something up because decrypting the file just gives 
gibberish. To make matters worse, *all* my backups are somehow 
corrupted (don't ask, I am not sure how either).

I am not going to make excuses: I know I messed up. Right now I want 
to focus on how I can fix the mess I've made.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Use vimzipper to wrap the encrypted file in a zip so it can be 
   cracked by standard zip crackers like fcrackzip, zipcracker, 
   pkcrack, Advanced Zip Password Recovery, etc. Unfortunately this 
   hasn't worked. I recovered a line of plaintext from the file 
   using the leftover info from the registers in my VIMINFO, but I 
   don't have the offset in the file for the recovered plaintext. 
   Regardless, the zip cracking hasn't worked, even for a simple 
   test file with a three-character vim password.

   (see http://zeus.phys.uconn.edu/refs/crackers/vimzipper.c)
2. Recovery of the swapfile didn't work. When I re-opened the 
   encrypted file with the bad password, vim overwrote the "good" 
   swapfile.
3. Run unixcrypt-breaker with a large database of plaintext (~30 
   books from Project Gutenberg) as reference data. This results in 
   gibberish, even if I only seed unixcrypt-breaker with the 
   recovered plaintext. Additionally, I can't seem to break even a 
   simple test file encrypted with vim using this method. (FYI, I am 
   stripping the VimCrypt~01! magic header before I run the 
   decryption and I strip it off using vim in PASTE mode so I don't 
   otherwise alter the file's contents).
4. Desperately guess every password and misspelling I can imagine. I 
   have spent at least six hours guessing what I could possibly have 
   spelled wrong. :)

In order to rapidly try passwords from a program, I tried compiling 
an old UNIX copy of crypt/makekey, but the result of that is not the 
same as the same file being encrypted using vim's -x encryption and 
the same password.

If anyone can help, I'd hugely appreciate it. If not, thanks for 
reading. :)

Comment: In some ways, I hope you don't succeed for everyone elses sake...

Comment: retrieve the copy you keep in your backup?

Comment: @Zoredache, Backups are all unrecoverable, even partially. I've tried.

@Darryl - I see what you mean. I will say, however, that Vim's encryption is based on the UNIX crypt, which is a single-rotor enigma system. This is well known to be breakable. Even the vim docs warn this.

Comment: @Darryl Hein: vim encryption is not considered cryptographically secure. For secure storage, use something like GnuPG.

Comment: So, what was your solution? What happened?

Comment: An interesting note: Vim 7.3 (2010-08-15) uses Blowfish encryption. Now that it has been released, you can put `set cm=blowfish` in your .vimrc to start using it (and never again be able to recover encrypted files! :) )

Comment: ^ except you very much _could_ break such encryption because `vim`'s original implementation of `blowfish` was poor and added severe vulnerabilities (above and beyond those native to the algorithm itself). thankfully it has since gained `blowfish2`, which is finally a respectable built-in crypt algo. source for all this: https://dgl.cx/2014/10/vim-blowfish and the vim patch notes linked therein.

Answer (score 26):

From the [VIM documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#encryption):

- The algorithm used is breakable.  A 4 character key in about one hour, a 6
  character key in one day (on a Pentium 133 PC).  This requires that you know
  some text that must appear in the file.  An expert can break it for any key.
  When the text has been decrypted, this also means that the key can be
  revealed, and other files encrypted with the same key can be decrypted.

If it was feasible on a Pentium 133, I think you have a very good chance. :)

I would either use #vim to ask for details on the algorithm or browse through the source code to figure out how the encryption is working and then write a cryptanalysis program.

Answer (score 10):

Is it possible that you could have data corruption issues in addition to your encryption problems?

If I was going to brute force this, I think I would write an algorithm that would start to try all variations of the passwords I could have used before moving on to dictionary attacks. Yet, after hearing your story - I have this nagging feeling that you didn't forget your password, but rather there was a data corruption issue somewhere along the way that messed up your password/crypttext/cryptokey/whatever.

Comment: You know, it seems obvious now that you say it, but you may be absolutely right. That would explain a few things. I do frequent backups, but not integrity checks. It's not malware (I scan regularly), but it is very possible that I have a data corruption issue. I'll look into it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this may help:

- [**Crypt Breaker's README**](http://axion.physics.ubc.ca/cbw.html)

Explains how to break a file encrypted with "crypt", might give you a starting point (at least with older versions of vi, the encryption was based on crypt).

Answer (score 5):

This ancient [newsgroup post](http://www.sunmanagers.org/archives/1998/0783.html) had a similar problem to yours:

> My problem was that I had accidentally encrypted a script using vi and could not recall the key.
>   many thanks to all those who responded.
>
> Suggestions were as follows:
>
> - use vi -x  and guess the key (I had tried that without success)
> - write a program which makes a crypt call and tries the likely key combinations.
>     the person who suggested this reckoned it would take about 5 minutes to crack
> - download CWB (crypt breakers work bench) form the archives which will help to crack
> - post the problem to sci.crypt.newsgroup including the first 128 bytes of the file after encryption
>     and these bytes before encryption (if i could remember) and somebody in the group might crack
>     it for me
> - re-type the script

One crib you have towards breaking this is you know what the password "should" have been.  So, even if you had a random typo, it would still slightly resemble your intended password.  Maybe you could start there, write a program to generate all possible combinations of your intended password with 1 or 2 character mispellings-additions.

In any case, what a neat exercise / diversion!

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old. Here is a modern solution:

Use hashcat (https://hashcat.net/hashcat/). Hashcat has a plugins for a wide set for cryptography algorithms and it allows you to specify and seed your (brute force starting point-) dictionary file with hints you still remember about your lost password.